# robocopy + skipping empty files

Tags: robocopy

Is there any way to exclude copying of empty files (0 bytes) using robocopy command?

I have a source with thousands of empty files besides other files and destination also have same file names but not empty. I want to copy everything from source to destination except empty files.

Answer (score 3):

Include command line switch `/MIN:1` what instructs Robocopy to ignore all files smaller than 1 byte.

From [documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

> /MIN:n : MINimum file size - exclude files smaller than n bytes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Robocopy documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Cc733145(v=WS.10).aspx) you should try to simply add `/min: 1`to your arguments